# Karaoke Style Captioning Youtube

Tags: animation, youtube, closed-captioning, transcription

I've noticed on a few youtube videos that captions can be animated to have karaoke style effects. How can you animate or fine-tune youtube transcriptions with custom animating like in the example below (top section). How much control do you have over this, and what's the extent of customization available so far?